# R different behavior when accessing columns from within function as opposed to interactively

Tags: r, function, subset

I have a data frame named `granular` that contains, in relevant part:

- factor column `GranularClass`, one of whose values is `"Constitutional Law I Spring 2016"`, and
- several numeric columns, for example `Knowledge`.  The numeric columns contain NAs.

I'm trying to write a function that counts the non-NA values for a given column, conditional on a given factor value. However, my attempt to count the values behaves differently depending on whether I write it as a function or just use it in the console.

More specifically, the following code fails:

```
# take subset of the dataframe containing only the factor values I want to look at:
isolate <- function(class) {
  return(granular[granular$GranularClass == class, ])
}

# count non-NA values:
cr <- function(df, column){
  return(sum(!is.na(df$column)))
}

# this fails
cr(isolate("Constitutional Law I Spring 2016"), Knowledge)
```

That last call gives incorrect output (it just returns 0), and throws a warning:

```
Warning message:
In is.na(df$column) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

However, this succeeds:

```
sum(!is.na(isolate("Constitutional Law I Spring 2016")$Knowledge))

# gives correct output: [1] 62
```

And, so... huh?  I believe that the working code in the last block is semantically identical to the function call in the first block that blows up.  But obviously that's not right.

Am I somehow passing the column name into the function wrong?  (Should I be passing it as a string?  But [this prior SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-as-a-string-in-a-v) suggests you can't pass strings into the `$` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've written two paragraphs as comments, I'll make them an answer:

`$` doesn't evaluate/parse the column name that follows. If you want to use a variable column name, the easiest way is a string column name with `[` or `[[`, not `$`. Try, for example, `x = 'mpg'`, `mtcars$mpg`; `mtcars$x`; `mtcars[, mpg]`; `mtcars[, 'mpg']`; `mtcars[, x]`. Note especially that `mtcars$x` *does not return a column*, even though `x` is defined as `'mpg'` and there is a column named `'mpg'`. This is the root of your problem and the main point of the question that you link to, [Select a data frame column using $ and the name of the column as a string in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18222286/903061). It doesn't matter that you are using `$` inside a function.

See also `fortunes::fortune(312)` and `fortunes::fortune(343)`.

But `mtcars$x` doesn't throw an error - it returns `NULL` because there is no column named `'x'`. So the differences in behavior you are observing are because you are doing different things with the results and it is the downstream calls that throw errors. `is.na(NULL)` gives a warning and a 0-length result - which is summable to `0`. But no error here.

Your `isolate` function is weird because it relies on having a data frame in the global environment named `granular` with a column named `GranularClass`. It would be better practice to pass in the data frame, but whatever. This doesn't much matter unless this function is in a package being submitted to CRAN.

When you do `df$column`, *even though `column` is an argument to your `cr` function, because it is being used here as an argument to `$` and `$` is special, `column` is not evaluated*.

For your function to work, you should rewrite it to be

```
cr = function(df, column) sum(!is.na(df[, column]))
```

and call it as

```
cr(isolate("Constitutional Law I Spring 2016"), "Knowledge")
```

Using strings as column names is the only straightforward way to pass column names as arguments.

---

If you really want to pass unquoted column names, then use the `lazyeval` package. Its vignette is very good. But it will have write the standard-evaluating version as above, and write a non-standard evaluating wrapper around it. It's generally not worth the hassle.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much!  I knew something had to be wonky with that $ operator, but it's such a dark corner of the language I had no clue how to fix.  (And yeah, grabbing global variables is a big naughty, but this is just a personal hack script, so hey. :-) )